# Return type for PHP method which returns a database object?

Tags: php, return-type

What return type I should replace in **"WHAT?"** text.
And if the query returns no results?

I'm using PHP 7.1

The method is:

```
public function retrieveSomething(int $id_user): WHAT? {
    try {
        $this->sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE IdUser = :id_user';
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->execute();
        $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $stmt->closeCursor();
        return $row;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        throw $e;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php - so you just can leave specification for return type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php):

> `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`: returns an **anonymous object** with property names that
>   correspond to the column names returned in your result set

You have some examples among the user comments:

```
object(stdClass)#6 (3) {
  ["1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["3"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

So:

```
public function retrieveSomething(int $id_user): \stdClass {
}
```

... should work (I don't have PHP/7 here to test).

Also:

> The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, **`FALSE` is returned on failure**.

To avoid this, you should configure PDO to throw exceptions (which you apparently already did, and is a good idea by itself).

Additionally, I suggest you drop the try/catch blocks, they're completely redundant.

Comment: The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.

Comment: Also, on failure, an exception is thrown. So, the answer seems right.

Answer (score 2):

This is a post for my own question because I want to show the final code.

```
public function retrieveSomething(int $id_user): ?\stdClass {
    $this->sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE IdUser = :id_user';
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($this->sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(':id_user', $id_user, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $stmt->closeCursor();
    if ($row) {
        return $row;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Both *Álvaro González* and *Dymen1* are correct...the return type is **stdClass**, but I needed to use the backslash **\stdClass**. Maybe because I'm using Composer autoload.

If the query returns no results, the return value will be **boolean(false)** and the method throw the **TypeError**. To correct this I put the question mark **?\stdClass**. The PHP documentation says

> Type declarations for parameters and return values can now be marked
>   as nullable by prefixing the type name with a question mark

[PHP 7 New features](http://php.net/manual/en/migration71.new-features.php)

Comment: I've fixed the missing root namespace separator in my answer, thanks for reporting back. However, if you are not throwing PDO exceptions there's even less point in catching them. (Out of curiosity, what's the `?` syntax? I can't find it in the manual but it's valid nonetheless).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've fixed the PHP exception issue...thank you. Regarding the question mark `?` is used to mark as nullable... Please see my updated answer.

Comment: That's for the nullable link (I confess I missed that). I'll never understand why you catch exceptions just to re-throw them but I'll assume this is just redacted code and you want to log the exception or something.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález your are right. I don't need the try/catch block. Thanx!

Answer (score 1):

From the docs:

> The return value of this function on success depends on the fetch type. In all cases, FALSE is returned on failure.
>   PDO::FETCH_OBJ: returns an anonymous object

This would result in:

```
function retrieveSomething(int $id_user): stdClass {
```

But, what if the fetch fails? So you might want to check the result before returning it, that way you can prevent displaying errors to your users.